# deleting call log from mulit numbers?

Tags: android, string, uri, calllog

Need help with deleting call log from multi numbers, using the following code i can delete calls logs from an exatct number using a string, what i need is to be able to delete calls from the log from numbers in the string.

heres the code im using for deleting exact numbers:

```
String strUriCalls = "content://call_log/calls";
            Uri UriCalls = Uri.parse(strUriCalls);
            Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(UriCalls, null,
                    null, null, null);
            if (c.getCount() <= 0)

            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Call log empty",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            while (c.moveToNext())
            {
                //eg.what I need is:    String gonnabpref = "0750627663 09876756446 08987766545 0908977534";
                String gonnabpref = "0750627663";
                String queryString = "NUMBER='" + gonnabpref + "'";
                Log.v("Number ", queryString);
                int i = context.getContentResolver().delete(UriCalls,
                        queryString, null);
                  if (i >= 1)

                {
```

Hope this makes sense (noob) any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way by split string on the basis of space:

```
String gonnabprefd = "0750627663 09876756446 08987766545 0908977534";
String[] numarry=gonnabprefd.split(" ");
for(int i=0;i<numarry.length;i++)
{
String gonnabpref = numarry[i];
String queryString = "NUMBER='" + gonnabpref + "'";
Log.v("Number ", queryString);
int i = context.getContentResolver().delete(UriCalls,
 queryString, null);
 if (i >= 1)
  {
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, however im getting a syntax error on this part for(int i=0;i<numarry.length,  i++) { its the "," thats giving me syntax.. any ideas?

Comment: ohh,by mistch ,it's ; so plez change , to ;

Answer (score 1):

Numbers with a + sign at the beginning do not get deleted.